# Domain Driven Design - Using code first approach

Tags: entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design

Is it good practice to create a database from a domain model, using a code-first approach, which then dictates what the database schema looks like (using entity framework). Or should you always design the db first and then create you domain model(s)?

Comment: Db schema should be related but different from the domain model. I would say model Domain first THEN care about db, but modeling the Domain has nothing to do with db schema, EF or any database.

Comment: I would say **if you are trying to use a domain driven design paradigm you must do domain model first(via code, or modeler)**.  Shimming a domain model on top of an existing DB is not so fun and sometimes impossible.  That said EF allows all of the above, really depends on what you are after as to whether or not it is a _good_ idea

Answer (score 0):

From 2009 to 2013-ish, that's exactly what I have done (and answered many SO questions doing exactly that!) - using Entity Framework as our "Aggregate Roots" and extended them from there with value objects (poco classes) and so on.

I am here today to tell you this: DON'T DO IT!

The latest "rutt-rough" coming from DDD in C# is how most of us have done this - a direct "Table to Entity/Aggregate" mapping.  All this does is give a false sense of separation without any bounded contexts.

In the past, I usually created a folder called, say, "Users".  I also had an entity called User.cs for code first (or in the designer, a table called User).  I was allowed to add my own methods and properties onto a User.cs partial.  I would also group all value objects related to users within a subfolder.  So, it looked like this:

```
\Users\
  ^- User.cs partial with additional so called "logic"
   - UserService acting with "business logic" on User and related properties.

\users\EmailTemplates\
         ^- I often needed a way in DDD to store other "Entities" related to this AR.

\Users\ValueObjects\
         ^- UserAddress.cs
          - UserTarget.cs
          - UserTypeEnum.cs
          - // basically a dumping ground
```

Now, after a year, we've come to realize that we have so much work on UserTarget that it is huge.  It is becoming a huge service-like class with 1000 lines of code.  In DDD, this really should be it's own bounded context, called `UserTargets` and act as its own aggregate root, with many value objects in it.  But yet, there isn't anything stored in the DB.  Do we create a entity in code first?  have an exception in attributes to ignore it?  etc.

It just feels so dirty and hacky any way you cut it.

Let's take another example out of the DDD playbook:

Biz: "I have a user that needs to signup.  Once they signup, they will have a project."

Dev team: "Great, we have the following entities: User and Project"

```
public class User {
  public List<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
  public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team {
  public List<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project {
  public User Administrator { get; set; }
  public List<User> Members { get; set; }
}
```

That alone is a problem.  Now that we are using CQRS/event sourcing often, it's easier to model it more like:

```
User : AggreateRoot
Team : AggregateRoot
Project : AggregateRoot
UserProject : AggregateRoot
UserSignup : AggregateRoot
TeamProject : AggregateRoot
...etc
```

Note the additional aggregates?  How would you represent them in the DB?  FKs right?  Well, what if there are additional properties like a TeamProject.ContestEntrySubmitted datetime?  Ah yes, now those FK child tables get ugly in EF and code first.

The domain is for your pure business design - to solve solutions.  Not for how many POCOs you can organize to make EF happy in code gen.  Not as your CRUD layer to bypass all business logic, new up an ObjectContext, and call Save(new User()).  I see developers wasting so much time with this or that EF issue, wrestling with "do we side-step DDD to make EF do `this`?  or do we spent a few days changing EF's internals and T4s to do `that` instead?  we'll remain DDD-ish, but many that's a lot of work."

So I am hear to ask, "Why do it at all?"  Separate the domain from any storage model.

In CQRS, your "Domain" is write-only anyways.  Having them as a EF objects already throws event sourcing out the window, and now forces you to handle states.

By freely writing domain aggregates and entities allows us to bind multiple projects, or users, to each other without affecting the other aggregates.  if the other aggregates, say User, wants to have a project count, sure, listen for the ProjectCreated event for that userid who created it and ProjectCount++ and call in the day.

The point is, once you apply DDD to Event Sourcing patterns, you look at your domain quite differently.  It is no longer a "stateful" domain in a sense that you can query anytime to get the last 10 years who signed up, or knowing you can just go to the DB and run that SQL.  No, instead it is more like, "I need to make a state change to X entity.  It will be caused by this, this and that when in these specific states.  Now, when the planets have aligned, we'll change the Username to be this in a new ChangedUSernameBecausePlanetsAligned event."

I guess my point I am trying to make is going down the EF Entities-as-DDD AggregateRoots feels so dry in the end, and without any DDD substance.  You end up with nearly 30 or 50 "aggreateroot" folders in your monolithic MyProject.Domain assembly.  And is what Udi basically calls, a Big Ball of Mud.

My general rule now is not to use any frameworks for my domain - freeing me up to structure it in pure DDD as I see fit, and it has been really enjoyable.  There are no confining frameworks or restrictions.  I've actually re-written entire domains in F#, just for fun and since there was no need for any "queries", it just happened.

Then, wjem moving into the Event Sourcing world, you start to realize exactly why your domain is "write only" and think about how you can "push" data to the views, instead of giving the views something to query from your domain.  Removing that Querying part from your domain really makes this nice and neat.

--
Eh, I think I just realized that I wrote an answer that basically says, "Hey, don't do Entity Framework and DDD.  Check out CQRS and DDD instead."  LOL